# Parse data using Splunk and Regular Expression

Tags: regex, splunk

I have string data like that: "**CONNECT,,'select a,c',0**"

I am using Splunk and regular expression to parse this string, delimiter by comma (,).

Expected results:

1. CONNECT
2. Blank
3. select a,c
4. 0

How can I get data at col 2 and column 3?

Thank for your reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using regular expression. You might find it easier to use delimiter instead.

See this link might answer you question:
https://answers.splunk.com/answers/126532/props-conf-field-extraction-for-a-csv.html

Cheers,
Vincent

Comment: Thanks Vincent, you saved my day. That's useful.